# How do I add a url with special character é (barlé.com) to Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to add a site to Google Analytics, [https://barlé.com](https://barl%C3%A9.com). It says the URL is invalid because of the special character é. When deploying on Heroku, Heroku recognizes the domain as -> xn--barl-epa.com. This is accepted by google analytics, but I don't get any data when using this other url.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "adding a site to Google Analytics"? If you are talking about the default url you enter whatever you want - the setting does not affect data collection, you just won't be able to use the preview feature (the little arrows next to the urls in the content reports), since that uses the default url as base url.

Answer (score 1):

Use a punycode substitute of the character.

Check out [this documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1081197?hl=en) for more.

Comment: Except that documentation points to using punycode which would be the same he uses for heroku `https://xn--barl-epa.com` ... guess the question is what does "This is accepted by google analytics, but I don't get any data when using this other url." mean? @Daniel